# how would I find the splitting field of $x^4+13$?

Tags: field-theory

I have the four roots but I am unsure how to proceed next, and how to show the degree of the extension over Q is 8.

Comment: Do you know what "splitting field" means?

Comment: it's the smallest field extension in which the polynomial splits, right? I have the 4 roots (via factoring), but not sure what to do next

Comment: Hint: $(x^4+13)(x^4-13) = x^8 -169$. So a root of your polynomial is also...

Answer (score 3):

By looking at the roots $$\sqrt[4]{-13},i\sqrt[4]{-13},-\sqrt[4]{-13},-i\sqrt[4]{-13}$$
it is clear that the splitting field is $$\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{-13})$$
that is since both $i\sqrt[4]{-13},\sqrt[4]{-13}$ is in the splitting
field hence $\frac{i\sqrt[4]{-13}}{\sqrt[4]{-13}}=i$ is.

Now we need to find $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{-13}):\mathbb{Q}]$.

Argue
that $i\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-13})$ by using that fact that
$\sqrt{13}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, deduce that the degree is $8$ by noting
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-13}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ since it is a simple extension
and $x^{4}+13\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible